# Do TList<TPair<UInt32, UInt32>> need to be free?

Tags: delphi

I wrote code

```
procedure Pair;
var
  PairList: TList<TPair<UInt32, UInt32>>;
  LPair: TPair<UInt32, UInt32>;
begin
  PairList := TList<TPair<UInt32, UInt32>>.Create;
  try
    PairList.Add(LPair.Create(4,10));
  finally
    PairList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I free the PairList, The Pair that I've created need to be freed too?

Comment: `LPair.Create(4,10)` urgh, constructor on a value type instance. Embarcadero are trying to make you suffer. FWIW, this pair type isn't very appropriate here. It's designed for a dictionary. Don't just use a type that happens to have the right number of members, ignoring the fact that their names are not appropriate.

Comment: could you please suggest me, I want two values that put in TList

Comment: Declare a record type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to free `TPair` variables, because it is a value type - record declared as

```
  TPair<TKey,TValue> = record
    Key: TKey;
    Value: TValue;
    constructor Create(const AKey: TKey; const AValue: TValue);
  end;
```

If you try releasing it with `LPair.Free` you would get compiler error

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Free'